# Where can I get Smritis in english or Hindi Translation?

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras, smriti

I was searching over the Internet for a long time to find and read the Smriti but it didn't help. Is there any source where I can read all 18 major & minor Smritis online or offline with commentary (if it's available)?
Thanks.

The smritis I'm looking for

Major:

(1) Manu (2) Bruhaspati (3) Dakha (4) Gowtama (5) Yama (6) Angirasa (7) Yogeswara (8) Pruchita (9) Satatapa (10) Parasara (11) Samvarta (12) Usana (13) Sankhya (14) Likhita (15) Atri (16) Vishnu (17) Apasthamba (18) Harita.

Upasmritis:

(1) Jabali (2) Nachiketas (3) Skanda (4) Lokashi (5) Kasyapa (6) Vyasa (7) Sanat kumar (8) Santana (9) Janaka (10) Kratu (11) Katyana (12) Jatukarni (13) Kapinjala (14) Bodhyana (15) Kanada (16) Viswamitra (17) Paithinasa (18) Gobhila.